# Android Design Support Library: FloatingActionButon (FAB) displaying correctly on earlier versions of android and incorrectly on Lollipop

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport

I have added Android Design Support Library. I am testing the app with two emulators, running Lollipop and Jellybean.  The Jellybean version is displaying the FAB correctly. On the Lollipop version the FAB does't have elevation or margins. Any suggestions on fixing this issue?

Below I have posted post the layout, Activity and two images showing the difference.  If you need more code let me know and I will post it.

Note: I have removed most of the code not pertaining to the question.

**Layout**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imShadow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow"
            android:orientation="vertical"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_search"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbarMain;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        iniToolbarMain();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbarMain);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        final CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Hello World!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
                }).show();
            }
        });

    }

    private void iniToolbarMain() {
        toolbarMain = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbarMain.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);
        toolbarMain.setTitle("Hello World");
        toolbarMain.setNavigationIcon(R.mipmap.ic_menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            handleToolbar.handleToolBar(search, toolbarMain, MainActivity.this);
            etSearch.requestFocus();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Jellybean**

[image]

**Lollipop**

[image]

Comment: Someone took the trouble and made rather extensive testing on mentioned FAB behaviour ; https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175185 .

Answer (score 6):

Add boderWidth = "0dp"

```
       app:borderWidth="0dp"
       app:elevation="4dp"

       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="8dp"/>
```

Comment: borderWith actually does fix the issue with elevation.

Comment: Just a small pointer, guidelines say FAB margin must be 16dp and not 8
:-)

Comment: borderWith="0dp" also fixed issue with FAB being square instead of round on Jelly Bean devices

Comment: Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Add `right` and `bottom` margin to your `android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton` widget XML. If you want to customize **FAB** elevation then just use attribute **app:elevation**.

**FAB XML:**

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_search"
    app:fabSize="normal"/>
```